# How to allow layout.pack() size to be free form in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, circle-pack

I'm using the d3.layout.pack(), where I have a bunch of data represented in circles of varying sizes. These circles sizes change, but how do I also make the outermost circle (the circle in which all the nodes are bound in) change in size? I want to show increase/decrease changes in the total numbers.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you need to change the size of the pack layout using the [`.size()` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pack-Layout#wiki-size). You could use a scale to make it scale with the maximum number, e.g.

```
var s = d3.scale.sqrt().domain([min, max]).range([100, 500]);
packLayout.size([s(thisMax), s(thisMax)]);
```

Comment: Hi, do you have a solution for my Bubble Chart: https://jsfiddle.net/desmeit/ukL7qo2e/4/

Comment: A solution for what? You may want to post a new question about this.